# mongodb reduce function returning incorrect resilts

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I am trying to do a calculation on the values array from the map function but when i perform calculations on the elements of values they are wrong yet when i interrogate the array itself the values are correct. Here is my map function :

```
function Map() {
var tempDate = new Date(Date.parse(this.date));
var day = Date.UTC(tempDate.getFullYear(), tempDate.getMonth(), tempDate.getDate());
var sensorTime = Date.UTC(tempDate.getFullYear(), tempDate.getMonth(), tempDate.getDate(),tempDate.getHours(), tempDate.getMinutes(), tempDate.getSeconds(), tempDate.getMilliseconds());
sensorTime = sensorTime - day;
emit(
        day,
        {time : sensorTime, 
         seq : parseInt(this.seq_no) }
         ); 


}
```

in the reduce function I sort the values array by sensorTime and then try to subtract the first element.seq from the last element.seq but I always get an incorrect answer. :-

```
function Reduce(key, values) {


var len = values.length;
var a = 0;
var b = len -1;


// ascending order
function SortByTime(x,y) {
return parseInt(x.time) - parseInt( y.time); 
}
values.sort(SortByTime);


return {time : 0, seq : (values[b].seq - values[0].seq)};

}
```

if I just return one of the values without the calculation then it is correct. I have tried forcing type to number but didn't make any difference. I am sure I am missing something obvious.

thanks

Comment: The difference is not commutative. Not sure what you are trying to compute? It would help if you could post your data (or a small set of example data that exhibits the issue) and the expected result.

Comment: Your code assumes that the reduce function will be called only once per key, which is wrong. It can be called zero or more times. And, moreover computing results per key in your case should be done in the finalize function, please go through - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/#calculate-order-and-total-quantity-with-average-quantity-per-item.

Comment: thanks looks like I can't do what I need to with map reduce as order as is extremely important for my data as there are gaps I need to take account of by using a sequence number. I still wonder if there is something odd about the javascript though ,I can't see any combination of numbers in my list that could return the results I am getting.